# Downloadable product with shipping

Tags: magento-1.7, product, shipping, bundled-product, downloadable

I have setup where i sell mp3 products with 3 options.

```
A) Download only (Type: downloadable product - no shipping)
B) Physical product CD only (Type: simple product - shipping)
C) Download + CD (Type: ? - shipping)
```

What is important here is that option B and C needs to have shipping enabled but not A, bacause i need shipping for external webservice (labels + automatically import tracking number etc.).

So far i have tried a bundled product with 3 associated products (1 downloadable, 1 simple and 1 ?). This works fine for option A and B but not C.

I am unsure if this is the right approach. I am also considering adding option C as simple product and then somehow include downloadlink in mail and customer account for only one simple product.

What is right approach for this setup? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try this - keep the bundled product the way you have it, but with just the two associated products.  Then go into the simple product and add the downloadable product as a "Related Product".  I believe then you could let the user select physical or download, and if they select physical, then it would let them check a box to "add the download product".  Would that work?

Comment: Sorry this is not the solution i am after. I need solution where customer pays shipping + get download links in email + customer account.

Comment: I think it could work - because if the customer selected the simple product and then checked the box for the downloadable product, then the customer would be ordering both products.  You wouldn't have a third product - just would be making it simple for them to order two products.  Then the user would get a shipping charge and they would also get the download links.  If you must have a third separate product, however, my idea wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have finally solved this.

I went ahead with bundled product solution.

I created 3 products underneath the bundled.

2 was simple and 1 downloadable.

1. **Downloadable product:**
   Needed to modify downloadable product to be able to select in bundle + email for downloadlinks, as they are not included in the default bundled email template.

*No shipping required.*

2. **Simple product:**
   Default simple product that enables shipping.

*Shipping required.*

3. **Simple product:** 
   Created new attribute set with 2 new attributes. Title and download link. Modified the email template so these were visible in email. This would enable shipping + let customers download. Links are included in email as soon as payment has been authorized (processing).

*Shipping required.*

As i have disabled customer login i dont need to show download links in customer account also there are unlimited download per link. This simplified requirements, so the above solution works just fine.